# Google sheets script for changing reference

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Tried google, tried the search but didn't find a direct answer.

I have tabs named 2000, 2001, 2002 etc.
I have a main tab where I have references to these numbered tabs with different financial values and calculations.
I would like to change the references with two buttons (+ and -). At the same time a number 2000 etc. could be displayed in the main tab.

I have until now used search and replace. But the script would be easier and faster.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you share a link to your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named ranges.

Right click on the first cell referencing a year on your main tab. Choose 'Define named range'. Set the name to something like 'Year1'.

Everywhere you want to reference this year use the formula `=Year1`.

If you are referencing the sheets use `=INDIRECT(Year1&"!A1:A2")` etc.

[Named Ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)